# Can you import only the 2nd Sheet from Excel to Access using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

Can you import only the 2nd Sheet from Excel to Access using VBA?!  I did some Googling on this and couldn't find a definitive answer.

Here is the code that I'm trying to get working.

```
strPathFile = Fil

objXL.Visible = True
Set wkb = objXL.Workbooks.Open(strPathFile)
For Each wks In wkb.Worksheets
    If wkb.wks = wkb.Sheet(2) Then
        DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9, strTable, strPathFile, blnHasFieldNames
    End If
Next
```

I'm trying to import data from a bunch of Excel files, always from the second sheet in the file, but each sheet has a different name.

Comment: `sheets(2).name` would give you the sheet name... Other qualifiers than `.name` should get you to other commands/properties

Comment: Is this Excel VBA?  Or is it Access VBA?  (I didn't think Excel had a `DoCmd` statement.)

Comment: The Access VBA [`DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/access-vba/articles/docmd-transferspreadsheet-method-access) has more parameters than you are using.  One of them is `Range`.  You may be able to use it to specify the range (including sheetname?) that you want to import.  I was going to post an answer to that effect, but I didn't have enough experience with Access VBA to get a test to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it turns out, I was missing 2 things.

```
1)  wks.Index = 2

2)  NeedThisSheet = wks.Name & "!"
```

Here is the code snippit.

```
strPathFile = Fil

objXL.Visible = True
Set wkb = objXL.Workbooks.Open(strPathFile)
For Each wks In wkb.Worksheets
    If wks.Index = 2 Then
        NeedThisSheet = wks.Name & "!"
        DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9, strTable, strPathFile, blnHasFieldNames, NeedThisSheet
    End If
Next
wkb.Close
```

Thanks everyone!!