# Referencing Excel sheet name by index in access VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access

I've got a sub that imports an Excel sheet into a table, but the problem I have is the workbook sheet name changes every time.

Is there any way I can reference the sheet name by index or some other way instead.

```
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12, TableName, selectFile(), False, "sa290918-2 Run In!A2:J50"
```

Comment: Maybe you could open the Excel file and get the worksheet name from there? Something like `Application.workbooks("workbook name").worksheets(1).name`,  which should return a string -- which you can then feed to `DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet`. Would something like that work in your use case?

Comment: hey, thanks for the reply, thats a possible option, i will look into it.

Comment: If it's always the first sheet then just remove the sheetname: `DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12, TableName, selectFile(), False, "A2:J50"`

Comment: For the option @chilin mentioned  look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45313728/6600940)

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet would be as chillin states, have a function to return the name of the n'th worksheet just before you do the import. It would mean opening the workbook though. Alternatively, you could used a BOOK LEVEL named range. Then you don't specify either the worksheet name or a cell range.